# MySQL JDBC driver failed to create schema with hyphen

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have an application with schema per tenant architecture. But when the tentant name contains hyphen, schema creation failed.
The datasource creation:

```
HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
ds.setUsername(username);
ds.setPassword(password);
ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tenant-test");
ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
ds.addDataSourceProperty( "allowMultiQueries" , "true" );
ds.addDataSourceProperty( "autoReconnect" , "true" );
ds.addDataSourceProperty( "characterEncoding" , "UTF-8" );
ds.addDataSourceProperty( "useUnicode" , "true" );
ds.addDataSourceProperty( "createDatabaseIfNotExist" , "true" );
ds.getConnection(); // exception thrown here
```

Is there any property I have to set? When schema exists, everything works fine. Also schema without hyphen is created successfully. Based on the stack trace, it looks like an issue in mysql jdbc driver.

Exception stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:905) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:830) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-test' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:816) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.checkErrorMessage(NativeProtocol.java:741) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:671) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.changeDatabase(NativeProtocol.java:543) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:706) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1449) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:165) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:849) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.14.jar:8.0.14]
```

**EDIT:**

I think it's a bug. I looked into mysql connector sources and I found out that the db name is not quoted...

NativeProtocol.java, row 542:

```
if (this.getPropertySet().getBooleanProperty(PropertyKey.createDatabaseIfNotExist).getValue()) {
                sendCommand(this.commandBuilder.buildComQuery(getSharedSendPacket(), "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + database), false, 0);
...
```

Comment: "I think it's a bug." - I agree. I didn't find any hits at https://bugs.mysql.com/ so you might want to report this issue there.

Comment: BTW, I reproduced the issue directly with `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource` from mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar

Comment: @GordThompson https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95564

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the dash (hyphen) character is not a permitted character in an unquoted identifier.

Rules for identifiers are documented here in the MySQL Reference Manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html

---

To use the hyphen character, the identifier must be quoted. Normally we use backtick characters, e.g.

```
 SELECT `foo` FROM `bar`
```

---

If sql_mode includes ANSI_QUOTES, we can use double quotes to escaped identifiers.

---

MySQL is reporting  ubiquitous error 1064. That's getting reported in the stack trace:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-test' at line 1

Comment: I know I can create db with hyphen in the name with a sql command using backticks. But in my case the db is created by mysql driver (createDatabaseIfNotExist is true) and it seems the driver is not using the backticks. I'm asking if there is any property to tell the driver to use backticks or it's a bug.

Comment: @Michal: so if you already know all those things ... then why have you not attempted to quote/escape the database name in the JDBC URL?

Comment: I tried it, but wasn't working... ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ + URLEncoder.encode("`tenant-test`", "UTF-8")); causes no db (even without hyphen) cannot be found.

Comment: This exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJException: Unknown database '` `tenant` `'